# How to call define a simple function?

Tags: functions

I am new to Mathematica I have a simple question.

I have the following definition:

```
f[i_,j_] := Integrate[KroneckerDelta[i, j] - ki * kj + Exp[-(kx^2+ky^2)], 
{kx, 0, 10}, {ky, 0, 100}]
```

I would like to write it in a way that if I call `f[x,x]` it would compute:

```
f[x,x] = Integrate[KroneckerDelta[x, x] - kx * kx + Exp[-(kx^2+ky^2)],{kx, 0, 
10}, {ky, 0, 100}]
```

or if I call `f[x,y]` it returns:

```
f[x,y] = Integrate[KroneckerDelta[x, y] - kx * ky + Exp[-(kx^2+ky^2)],{kx, 0, 
10}, {ky, 0, 100}]`
```

Comment: Surely just: `f[x_] := A^2 x^2` and 
`f[b_, q_] := A^2 b q`?

Comment: I do not realy get the question: if you call your $f[b,q]$ with the arguments $x,x$ it does what you wanted with $f[x,x]$. You should maybe specifiy your question a bit more.

Comment: It's hard even to formulate the question because I am not familiar with it. I edited it, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Please always post code as plain text, not LaTeX.  Put it in a code block (see ? button in the editing toolbar for help).  Make sure that it can be copied and pasted back in to Mathematica.  It is hard to tell from what you posted if your function definition is even valid ...

Comment: That is an extremly strange function; I mean you just want to return some powers of ten why dont you just use  `f[a_, b_: 0] := 10^(a + b)`. Or why do you even need such a "function"?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, what I really what is the following function:
`f[i_,j_] = Integrate[KroneckerDelta[i,j] - ki * kj Exp[-(kx^2 + ky^2)],{x,0,10}, {y,0,10}]`

I want to change ki and kj to kx or ky depending on the way I call the function.

Comment: Please add anything relevant to your question, not just as a comment.

Comment: I suspect the question would be more clear (and you might answer it yourself) it you didn't try to use the same `x,y` local symbols in the function as the global symbols in the call.  ie. think what results you want for `f[p,p]` and `f[p,q]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $1-\delta_{xy}$ and $\delta_{xy}$ to get your two different terms $a*b$ and $a*a$:

```
f[x_, y_] := Integrate[KroneckerDelta[x, y] - KroneckerDelta[x, y]*(a*a) - (1 
- KroneckerDelta[x, y])*(a*b) + Exp[-(a^2 + b^2)], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

This gives for $$f[x,x]=\int_0^{10}da\int_0^{10}db ~e^{-a^2-b^2}-a^2+1=-3232.55$$ and for $$f[x,y]=\int_0^{10}da\int_0^{10}db ~e^{-a^2-b^2}-a b=-2499.21.$$

Comment: Smart.Thank you!